# Custom view with CALayer wired effect when animating bounds change

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, calayer

I have implemented a custom view with adding `CALayer` as sublayer for `UIView`. When I animate the view with the following:`UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0) { self.slider.bounds.size *= 2.0}`, the scaling animation is kind of wrong. The `CALayer` start at the wrong position with scaled size and move to the final position instead of scaling with the view.

The CustomeView Code :

```
import UIKit

class GridMaskView: UIView {
    private let cornerLayer: CAShapeLayer
    private let borderLayer: CAShapeLayer
    private let gridLayer: CAShapeLayer

    private let gridSize: (horizontal: UInt, vertical: UInt) = (3, 3)
    private let cornerThickness: CGFloat = 3.0
    private let cornerLength: CGFloat = 20.0
    private let borderThickness: CGFloat = 2.0
    private let gridThickness: CGFloat = 1.0
    private let lineColor: UIColor = UIColor(r: 120, g: 179, b: 193, a: 1)

    var showGridLines: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            gridLayer.hidden = !showGridLines
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        cornerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        cornerLayer.fillColor = lineColor.CGColor

        borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        borderLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.CGColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = borderThickness

        gridLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        gridLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.CGColor
        gridLayer.lineWidth = gridThickness

        super.init(frame: frame)
        layer.addSublayer(cornerLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(gridLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layoutLayers()
    }

    private func layoutLayers() {
        drawCorner()
        drawBorder()
        drawGrid()
    }

    private func drawCorner() {
        cornerLayer.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: -cornerThickness, dy: -cornerThickness)
        cornerLayer.path = cornerPath(forBounds: cornerLayer.bounds)
    }

    private func cornerPath(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGPathRef {
        let horizontalSize = CGSize(width: cornerLength, height: cornerThickness)
        let verticalSize = CGSize(width: cornerThickness, height: cornerLength)

        let corners: [(CGRectEdge, CGRectEdge)] = [(.MinXEdge, .MinYEdge), (.MinXEdge, .MaxYEdge), (.MaxXEdge, .MinYEdge), (.MaxXEdge, .MaxYEdge)]

        var cornerRects = [CGRect]()
        for corner in corners {
            cornerRects.append(bounds.align(horizontalSize, corner: corner.0, corner.1))
            cornerRects.append(bounds.align(verticalSize, corner: corner.0, corner.1))
        }

        let cornerPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathAddRects(cornerPath, nil, cornerRects, cornerRects.count)

        return cornerPath
    }

    private func drawBorder() {
        borderLayer.frame = bounds
        borderLayer.path = borderPath(forBounds: borderLayer.bounds)
    }

    private func borderPath(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGPathRef {
        let borderPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
        let borderCornerPoints = [bounds.topLeft, bounds.topRight, bounds.bottomRight, bounds.bottomLeft, bounds.topLeft]
        CGPathAddLines(borderPath, nil, borderCornerPoints, borderCornerPoints.count)

        return borderPath
    }

    private func drawGrid() {
        gridLayer.frame = bounds
        gridLayer.path = gridPath(forBounds: gridLayer.bounds)
    }

    private func gridPath(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGPathRef {
        let stepSize = bounds.size / (CGFloat(gridSize.horizontal), CGFloat(gridSize.vertical))

        let gridPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
        for i in (1...gridSize.vertical) {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * stepSize.width
            CGPathMoveToPoint(gridPath, nil, x, 0)
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(gridPath, nil, x, bounds.size.height)
        }

        for i in (1...gridSize.horizontal) {
            let y = CGFloat(i) * stepSize.height
            CGPathMoveToPoint(gridPath, nil, 0, y)
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(gridPath, nil, bounds.size.width, y)
        }
        return gridPath
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: cornerLength * 2, height: cornerLength * 2)
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to fit this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you do view animation you don't get *any* automatic animation of sublayers. You'd be better off using a subview of your original UIView, because view animation will animate that together with the original view, according to its autolayout constraints.

Comment: I am implementing a custom grid view. It seems that using UIView for every lines seem to a little bit strange. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: You have concealed everything about what you are actually doing and what the problem actually is. You've shown five lines of totally uninformative code. You want better help? Reveal, do not conceal. Better info, better question, better answer. Right now you're lucky to have anyone talking to you at all.

Comment: Well, I stand by what I said. You could be doing all that drawing into the main layer of a single view, make it a subview of your other view, and get the benefit of automatic subview animation. Otherwise you're going to have to animate all those layers yourself when you animate the view.

Comment: So I create a custom CALayer class and create a UIView and override its layerClass to my CALayer class?

Comment: Yes, or even just use a plain vanilla UIView and draw right into it.

Comment: I have convert my code into plain vanilla UIView. I would like the corner path stay the same size when resizing, how can I do that?